# Adding image to database along with other fields in webforms asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a table students with columns

id primary key, firstname, lastname,picture.
picture datatype is varbinary(MAX)

I am working with WebForms in ASP.NET.

I have this stored procedure.

```sql
create procedure spAddStudents
(
    @id int,
    @firstname nvarchar(50),
    @lastname nvarchar(50),
    @picture varbinary(MAX)
)  
as  
Begin  
    insert into students
    values (@id, @firstname, @lastname,@picture)  
End
```

In the webform I wrote this code

```cs
string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        string filename = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
        string filepath = "Images/" + FileUpload1.FileName;
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/") + filename);
                       
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spAddStudent",con);
                                            
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", txtFirstName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", txtLastName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@picture",filepath);

        con.Open();
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (i != 0)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Record inserted successfully";
        }
    }
}
```

when I gave image as datatype for picture in storedprocedure I get this error at line
cmd.executeNonQuery()

> Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with image

when I gave varbinary(max) as datatype for picture in storedprocedure I get this error

> Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: You can store the picture in your directory and keep a URL path for the image in the database. I think that's the best practice

Comment: `filepath` is a string and you said you defined `@picture` as a `VARBINARY(MAX)`. Do you want to save `FileUpload1.PostedFile` to the database? Or do you want to save the file to disk and store a file path in the database?

Comment: I want to store it to database. error at cmd.executeNonQuery()

Comment: You need to be specific and clarify what "it" is. Do you want to store the image as a binary, or do you want to store the path to the image on disc?

Comment: You can do the way I mentioned first. and to bind the data you can bring back that URL from the database and you can access the file using the file path

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you're trying to insert the path to the file on the hard drive (a string) into a varbinary field which is why you are getting this error. Instead skip writing the file to the hard drive, get the bytes as an array and then write that to your database field instead.

```
MemoryStream uploadstream = new MemoryStream();
HttpPostedFile.InputStream.CopyTo(uploadstream);
var picturearray = uploadstream.ToArray();
List<SqlParameter> Parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("picture", picturearray ));
```

This code works with 'Image' as the type on the database table. It may also work with Varbinary(MAX) using Parameters.AddWithValue(

Comment: Sir,  it is adding record into database but it immediately displays No FIle Chosen besides fileupload control.

Comment: Your code wouldn't progress beyond the if (FileUpload1.HasFile) and create the record if the file hadn't uploaded successfully. Your page is just refreshing on submit and isn't retaining the uploaded file between postback/submission which is the expected behaviour.